# Gradle copying and rename files

Tags: gradle

I have to write gradle task which will be copying files. Files are stored at tests/[Name]/test.txt and for each Name I want to create numbered directory /tested/test00/, /tested/test01/ etc. and in each catalog should be one file (test.txt from source folder renamed to test00, test01 etc.)
I have the code, but behavior is strange...
It creates correct directories /tested/test00 etc. but all files in each directory have the same name... test06. So number in directory is correct but in file name it isn't.

My code is:

```
int copyTaskIterator = 0
int testIterator = 0 
...

sources.each { mySource ->
    task "myCopyTask$copyTaskIterator"(type: Copy)
    nameSuffix = String.format("%02d", testIterator)
    fromPath = 'tests/'+mySource+'/test.txt'
    toPath = "tested/test"+nameSuffix

    tasks."myCopyTask$copyTaskIterator".from fromPath
    tasks."myCopyTask$copyTaskIterator".into toPath
    tasks."myCopyTask$copyTaskIterator".rename { fileName ->
        fileName.replace '.txt', nameSuffix
    }

    preBuild.dependsOn tasks."myCopyTask$copyTaskIterator"
    copyTaskIterator++
    testIterator++
}
```

Comment: Did you forgot a opening curly bracket, or is the indention incorrect?

Comment: the indention was incorrect, i just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `nameSuffix` is evaluated too late. Sadly no documentation explains whether it is executed in execution time or not.
Just try to use `rename(java.util.regex.Pattern, java.lang.String)`

```
tasks."myCopyTask$copyTaskIterator".rename("\\.txt", nameSuffix)
```

Comment: Now it's working great, but I really don't understand why...
Could you explain why it works with regex?

Comment: The way you wanted to rename your files uses a closure, which needs the name of the files. I am not sure when it will be executed exactly, but I think during the execution phase of gradle, because before that it can't determine the file name. Since you overwrite `nameSuffix` it refers to the last value at that moment. With the other rename method you use good old parameters, which are passed immediately.